# How can i get all values of JSON array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, response

I have this JSON response:

```
{
    "post_parameters_error_flag": false,
    "data_error_flag": false,
    "row_count": 7,
    "message": "Operazione completata.",
    "title": [
        "title0",
        "title1",
        "title2",
        "title3",
        "title4",
        "title5",
        "title6"
    ],
    "data": [
        "value0",
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3",
        "value4",
        "value5",
        "value6",
        "value7"
    ]
}
```

I need to write in a list (for example) all values obtained from 'data' array but I don't know how to get data from response:

```
string URL = "myurl";
string Params = string.Format("hwid={0}&building={1}", Utils.UUID(), "test");

Request HTTPRequest = new Request();

JObject JSONObject = JObject.Parse(await HTTPRequest.PostAsyncResponse(URL, Params));

//now? what can i do
```

Any idea to solve?

Comment: Since there has been a perfectly valid answer, I wanted to let you know there is a NuGet package for JSON called Newtonsoft which makes serializing and deserializing JSON relatively easy. It might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use like this:

```
var result = await HTTPRequest.PostAsyncResponse(URL, Params)
var token = JToken.Parse(result);
var data= token.Value<JArray>("data");
```

Or you can also use JsonPath:

```
var result = await HTTPRequest.PostAsyncResponse(URL, Params)
var token = JToken.Parse(result);
var data = token.SelectTokens("$.data[*]");
```

But really, you should be serilizing into an object and then using the properties to get the data (or other properties):

```
public class RootObject
{
    public bool post_parameters_error_flag { get; set; }
    public bool data_error_flag { get; set; }
    public int row_count { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<string> title { get; set; }
    public List<string> data { get; set; }
}

var result = await HTTPRequest.PostAsyncResponse(URL, Params)
var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
var data = item.data;
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved by serializing data into an object and accessing it from the properties

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var data = JObject.Parse(await HTTPRequest.PostAsyncResponse(URL, Params))["data"]
```

OR

```
var jsonObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await HTTPRequest.PostAsyncResponse(URL, Params));
var data = (JObject)(jsonObject.Property("data").Value);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already solved by following the solution of @andyb952